# What's the origin of the chirality selection rule?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-optics, topological-insulators, chirality

I'm reading this paper on Circular Photogalvanic Effect (https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys4146) and they mention a "chiral selection rule":

> Chirality selection rule: Right-handed circularly polarized (RCP) light along +z excites the +kz side of the χ =+1 Weyl node but the −kz side of the χ =−1 Weyl node. Chirality selection rule is independent of the tilt of the WFs.

But I cannot find any reference explaining the origin of this effect. So, how does this chirality selection rule arise?